# How to get data from specific column in firebird using rdb$field_name

Tags: firebird

how to get data from a specific column in fire bird? something like.

```sql
select from  rdb$relation_fields
where rdb$relation_name = 'table' and rdb$field_name = 'code'
```

Comment: I have made a guess as to what you need in my answer, but next time please be more specific as to what you need!

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't quite make sense to me - if you already know the table and field name (as you do in your example) then why not select directly from the table? Anyway, you can create SQL statement dynamically in PSQL as string and then execute it using [EXECUTE STATEMENT](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html). The [EXECUTE BLOCK](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-execblock.html) might also be of intrest, depends where and what exactly youre tring to achieve.

**EDIT after reading the comment**

So just build the SELECT statement at the client side, selecting the field currently selected in combobox. You don't mention the language you use but generaaly it something like

```
query.SQL := 'SELECT '+ comboField.Text +' FROM '+curTableName;
query.Open();
// read the resultset
```

Comment: Dear ain issue is i need to get data by column name thats why am not directly using simple select to get data . there is a combo which contain column names  so when i select column name from combo is should give the values of that specific column .